# Javascript closure not working as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, closures

I'm running this code on nodejs. I was wondering why the closure when executed does not print the string 'Globals'? Isn't the `this` in the closure pointing to the global scope?

```
// Running on NodeJS, not in a browser!
this.name = "Globals";

function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.namePrinter = function() {
    return function() {
      console.log(this.name);
    }
  }
}

var p = new Person("Faiz");
p.namePrinter()(); // prints undefined. Shouldn't it print Globals?
console.log(this.name); // prints Globals
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example works as intended in a browser, but in node.js `this` on the top level is not the same as `global`, it's your module `.exports`. So when you do

```
this.name = "Globals";
```

It assigns `name: Globals` to `module.exports`, not to the `global` object.

Now, when you write

```
p.namePrinter()();
```

it's the same as:

```
func = p.namePrinter();
func();
```

The function is unbound (= there's no `object.` before it), so its `this` will be the `global` object. But there's no `name` there...

In browsers, your top level code is executed in the context of the global object (which is `window`) and this is the same object unbound functions use. That's why your snippet works.

Comment: How did `setTimeout` come into the answer? I've fixed it, but I'm curious. Is this actually a dupe?